# php не видит cookie “/” в другой папке

Tags: php, cookie

Папка "/", устанавливаем `setcookie("a", 1, time()+3600*10101);`
Заходим в папку "/test", читаем кук 'a'. Кука нет.
Пошарился в интернете, пришел к выводу, что для каждой папки свои куки.
Как это исправить?

```
setcookie("id_admin", $_SESSION['id_admin'], time()+3600*24*14, $COOKIE_PATH, $domain);
setcookie("code_admin", $code_admin, time()+3600*24*14, $COOKIE_PATH, $domain);
```

Answer (score 1):

Всего лишь требовалось обратиться к официальной [**документации**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php)...

```
setcookie('cookiename', 'data', time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
```

1 параметр - имя куки
2 параметр - содержимое куки
3 параметр - срок куки (1 год)
4 параметр - по каким ссылкам кука доступна (`'/'` - на всех страницах/ссылках сайта).

Comment: Про самые главные параметры (5 и 6) связанные с безопасностью не написали.

Comment: @Visman, тогда не будет стимула зайти и почитать официальную документацию)))